# Removing a custom marker in HERE Maps Javascript API doesn't work

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

Removing a custom marker in HERE Maps Javascript API doesn't work.

Here is the way I add the marker:

```
function getLocation() {
        coord = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(window.latitude, window.longitude);
        var locationPushpin = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(coord, {
            icon: "images/icons/pushpin.png",
            anchor: new nokia.maps.util.Point(12, 12)
        });

        map.objects.add(locationPushpin);
};
```

And here is the code I am using to try to remove it from the map:

```
function removeClick() {
    map.objects.remove(locationPushpin);
};
```

However, it doesn't work. API Reference and the official Developer's Guide aren't of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, maybe you should declare you var locationPushpin outside the function getLocation(), if you want to use it later in another function.